# trying to use ng-options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Im trying to use ng-options, but my selectbox is still empty.

Here is my array containing objects:

```
 [Object { superkund_id="4", nod_id="12068", namn="Växjö Fagrabäck"}, Object { superkund_id="5", nod_id="9548", namn="Halmstad Bågen / Pilen"}]
```

Im trying to use the ng-option like this:

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-options="namn for namn in abbOptions"></select></td>
```

Here is my js-code:

```
$http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/abb/getDataOptionsForAbb/' + $rootScope.abbForm)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.abbOptions = data;
            console.log($scope.abbOptions);
        });
```

Anyone who can explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I solved it by writing like this:

```
item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in abbOptions
```

Comment: @YOU: That don't work. The selectbox Is still empty.

Comment: Add an `ng-model` to your `select`

Comment: @tymeJV: Thank you, I have done that, and the selectbox only ontains [object Object] rows. I solved it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ng-options` you need to include `ng-model` on your `select`

As for displaying the option text, your syntax is a bit off (unless you want the [object object]), it's `ng-options="value as text for item in array"` - assuming you want the ID as the value:

```
ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in abbOptions"
```

Comment: @tymejV: This don't work. The selectbox Is still empty